# xcode(ver6.1)で、cocoapodsでpopを入れたあとにBuild Faildになる。clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, cocoapods

xcode(ver6.1)で、アプリを作っているのですが、
アニメーションに使おうとcocoapodsでpopをインストールしました。

その後、Buildしようとしたところ「Build Faild」してしまいました。
以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

すいません、ド素人なのですが、いろいろググってみても解決策見つけられず。。。

どなたか解決策がお分かりでしたらお教え下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

エラーの詳細は、以下となります。

```
Ld /Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MuscleRace.app/MuscleRace normal i386
cd /Users/konya/Documents/apps/MuscleRace
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -FKiiTutorialApp -F/Users/moshiur/git/TutorialApp/iOSSDKTutorialApp -F/Users/konya/Documents/apps/MuscleRace -filelist /Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Intermediates/MuscleRace.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MuscleRace.build/Objects-normal/i386/MuscleRace.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-pop -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework Social -framework ImageIO -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -framework KiiSDK -framework Accounts -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Twitter -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Intermediates/MuscleRace.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MuscleRace.build/Objects-normal/i386/MuscleRace_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/konya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuscleRace-gtoenwwagxjhrkgnjvnipsmbjwcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MuscleRace.app/MuscleRace

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/moshiur/git/TutorialApp/iOSSDKTutorialApp'
ld: library not found for -lPods-pop
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: xcworkspaceを削除してpod installを再度動かしても問題が解決しないようなら、podfileを貼りつけていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

プロジェクトを開く際に「project名.xcworkspace」から開いていますか？
CocoaPodsを使用している場合は、「project名.xcodeproj」ではなく「project名.xcworkspace」から開く必要があったかと思います。

Comment: @monoru-nakamura さん  
  
回答、ありがとうございます。  
「project名.xcworkspace」こちらで開いてみましたがやはり同じエラーが出てしまいました。  
他に思い当たることはありますでしょうか？

Comment: あと思い当たるのだと、
Build Settings - Search Paths - Library Search Paths
のパスの指定先が正しくない時も同様のエラーになったかと思います。

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`のエラーメッセージのみだと原因特定が難しいので、
これより前のエラーメッセージも記載されたほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: 関連のありそうな箇所を質問に追記してみました。

Answer (score 1):

Build Settings - Search Paths - Library Search Pathsの指定が正しくないかもしれません。
"\"バックスラッシュが入っていたりしませんか？

以下の記事にも同じような問題が記載されています。
http://qiita.com/kuuki_yomenaio/items/b1b826a45ee6ff00eb90

Answer (score 0):

私も同エラーへ昨日、みまわれました。

Xcode(7.2)メニュー
　Product > clean
でなおりました。

ちなみにこれは
「An unknown error occurred」にても有効でした。